# Eclipse does not show projects in workspace

Tags: eclipse

I have opened Eclipse workspace that I transfered from another computer but it does not show any projects in package explorer (there should be a lot of them). Still project's folders are in workspace folder.

The new machine where I transfered the workspace runs Windows 7 that has the read-only folders issue ([more here](http://itexpertvoice.com/home/fixing-the-windows-7-read-only-folder-blues/)). That is all the folders that are created on that OS are read-only and that the read-only atribute cannot be removed in any way.

Eclipse originally refused to open the workspace at all saying that .metadata folder of the workspace is read only. After turning user control to the lowest level it opens the workspace but it acts as if it did not contain any projects. I think this is because Eclipse refuses to work with read-only folders and project folders are also read-only.

Did somebody have same problem? How did you solve it? Any suggestions are wellcome.

Comment: Try importing your Eclipse projects into a new workspace.

Comment: I often find that when I run into issues like this (workspace acting up) that just re-creating the workspace is the quickest way to get working again.

Comment: @reprogrammer How can we create a new workspace and open our projects there?

Comment: @Chris -  How can we create a new workspace and open our projects there?

Comment: @Hengameh - just like the first time you created your original workspace - choose a different folder for your workspace on startup, and import the projects like you did the first time...

Answer (score 5):

It is not enough to move your projects in the workspace path folder, you also need to import them. And because of they are in your path folder, you can't import them again because it will say you still have them in your workspace. Move them to another folder (for example in desktop), be sure your workspace folder is empty, and then try to import them from your temporary folder in desktop.

Comment: Workspace does not need to be empty, only not contain the same project. You also need to check "Copy projects into workspace" but good answer nonetheless.